# In access/SQL how do I make only the null values in a column equal to value in another column?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

[image]

I want to make only the blank cells in ATTRIB_VALUE equal to the values in ATTRIB_VALUE_NUM_9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
UPDATE *TABLE-NAME-HERE*

SET ATTRIB_VALUE=ATTRIB_VALUE_NUM_9

WHERE ATTRIB_VALUE IS NULL OR ATTRIB_VALUE =''
```

I'm not sure what your table name is based on your post, but I think that'll get you what you need.

Comment: Do I need to create a new query and use that in sql view? im getting an error on "UPDATE"

Comment: @user3893725 Probably. I don't use access myself but that should work. What error message are you getting?

Comment: It was an issue with the name of my query. I think your solution would work but the query im trying to update is not "updateable". Can I not use "SET" in the following code?

Comment: Nevermind. I see that SET can only be used with UPDATE. unfortunately I cant make this query updateable.

Comment: Not the most elegant solution probably but I made the query into a table then another query to update that table. Thanks for the help.